# Why is chat content not loading?

Tags: php, jquery, html, chat

I wanna make a jQuery chat, and I can't load the chat content into the chatbox..
Loading script (i use sessions for login so i needed to transfer the username to JS)

```
<?php 
    include "protect/1.php";
    print "<script type=\"text/javascript\">var name = '".$_SESSION['username']."'; </script>";
?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){ chat_update(name) });
    setInterval("chat_update("+name+")",1000);
    function chat_update(user) {
        $.post("response.php",{ username:user },function(data){
            $(".chatbox").html(data);
    }
</script>
```

And the div:

```
<div class="chatbox"></div>
```

If I open response.php (by a form that sends the post values), it loads all the messages. So it's pretty confusing..

EDIT: gonna add response.php, maybe the problem is there but i dont think so..

```
<?php
include "functions.php";
include "sql.php";
$iQuery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM chat ORDER BY id ASC");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($iQuery)) {
    if($row["to"] != null) {
        if($_POST["username"] == $row["to"] || $_POST["username"] == $row["sender"])
            echo "<span class=\"text\">".$row["date"]." | ".$row["sender"].": ".$row["message"]."</span><br>\n";
    }
    switch(getbyUser($_POST["username"],"level")) {
        case 1: echo "<span class=\"text\">".$row["date"]." | ".$row["sender"].": ".$row["message"]."</span><br>\n"; break;
        case 2: echo "<span class=\"text\">".$row["date"]." | ".$row["sender"].": ".$row["message"]."</span><a href=\"?page=admin/delmsg&msg=".$row["id"]."\"><img src=\"res/del.png\"></a><br>\n"; break;
        case 3:
        case 4: echo "<span class=\"text\">".$row["date"]." | ".$row["sender"].": ".$row["message"]."</span><a href=\"?page=admin/delmsg&msg=".$row["id"]."\"><img src=\"res/del.png\"></a><a href=\"?page=admin/editmsg&msg=".$row["id"]."\"><img src=\"res/edit.png\"></a><br>\n"; break;
    }
}
mysql_free_result($iQuery);
?>
```

Comment: First of all, your chatbox is a div? How is it getting any message from the user? Secondly, what is the overall goal you're trying to achieve?

Comment: "$(".chatbox").html(data);" thats how im trying to load the data from response.php

Comment: OK, and it's "loading all" messages even those where the username is not equal to `$row["to"]` or `$row["sender"]`?

Comment: What does `getbyUser` do?

Comment: $row["to"] and $row["sender"] are only for PMs. getbyUser reads a user attribute from the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax error in your `$.post` call, change to:

```
function chat_update(user) {
    $.post("response.php",{ username:user },function(data){
        $(".chatbox").html(data);
    }); // <-- this was missing
}
```

The second problem is here:

```
setInterval("chat_update("+name+")",1000);
```

By passing the `name` like that you are passing an unquoted string, for example:

```
chat_update(John) // <-- the string doesn't have quotes
```

A quick fix would be to add single quotes, but you need to make sure the username can't contain quotes itself.

```
setInterval("chat_update('"+name+"')",1000);
```

Answer (score 2):

assuming that is your live jquery code your $.post request is invalid which is why its not returning any data.

you havent closed the function(data) section off so it should be

```
function chat_update(user) {
    $.post("response.php",{ username:user },function(data){
            $(".chatbox").html(data);
    });
}
```